# Passing many argumentes (...) by ellipsis in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to pass arguments in rcpp function using ... but it is not working. How to do this correctly?

```
NumericVector function(SEXP xR, ...){
    NumericVector x(xR);
    int lenx = x.size();
    NumericVector ret(lenx);
    for(int i=0; i < lenx; i++){
        if(x[i]<0){
            ret[i] = 0;
        }else if(x[i]>1){
            ret[i] = 1;
        }else{  
            ret[i] = anotherfunction(x[i], ...);
        }       
    }
    return ret; 
}
```

In current version I get this error:
`expected primary-expression before '...' token`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Rcpp11` has the concept of variable number of arguments with the `Dots` and `NamedDots` class. You'd do something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp11>

List force_dots( const Dots& dots ){
    List out(n) ;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        out[i] = Rcpp_eval( dots.promise(i), dots.environment(i)) ;    
    }
    return out ;
}

// [[export]]  
List dots_example(NumericVector x, Dots dots){
    int n = dots.size() ;
    List args = force_dots(dots) ;
    return args ;
}

/*** R
    dots_example(1:10, "e" )
    # [[1]]
    # [1] "e"
*/
```

When you use `attributes::sourceCpp` on this file, you get an R function that has ellipsis:

```
> dots_example
function(x, ...){
  res <- .Call( "sourceCpp_dots_example" , x, environment())
  res
}
```

This only partly answers the question, i.e. how to pass down to C++ a variable number of arguments from R.

You'd also need something similar to R's `do.call` for when you call the `another_function` function. For now you sort of have to do it manually until we find a way to implement a useful `do_call`

Answer (score 6):

You may be confusing the R-language construct `...` with something you assume also exists in C++.  And while C++ does have `varargs` that is not supported by Rcpp due to the interface from R.  All we have is the `.Call()` interface

```
 SEXP somefunction(SEXP a, SEXP b, SEXP c, ...)
```

and here the `...` is used in a literal sense just for the exposition:  You can have 0, 1, 2, 3, ... `SEXP` arguments.  But those you use *must be fully qualified*.  In short, using `...` results in the syntax error you see. See [Section 5.9 of Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Handling-R-objects-in-C) for details.

And as a side note, this is why we have macro-generated code in Rcpp. Now, with C++11 you can also use variadic templates in C++ code (which Rcpp11 uses to great effect in its internal code) but that of course does not alter the interface to R which is still the same `.Call()` interface, and hence the same constraint. Variadic templates are very nice, and open for use in your C++ code with either Rcpp or Rcpp11, but they do not change the interface to R.  You need a fixed set of arguments, and can not rely on a variable number.

That said, if you just pass a `List` object as one of your arguments, then you can traverse it by position or name at will and check the content.  That is the closest in spirit to your question.